# windows form c# ftp uploader

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm having a problem using c# to upload files to an ftp server.

The window form opens but when I click on the upload button nothing happens.
I created a structure for the ftp logging information and the file to upload.
I think it's the `do_work` function where the problem is, but I can't seem to find it.

```
struct FtpSetting
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}

FtpSetting inputParameter;


private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).FileName;
    string fullname = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Fullname;
    string username = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Username;
    string password = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Password;
    string server = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Server;
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}",server,filename)));
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullname);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    double total = (double)fs.Length ;
    int byteRead = 0;
    double read = 0;
    do
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            byteRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
            read += (double)byteRead;
            double pourcentage = read / total * 100;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)pourcentage);
        }

    } while (byteRead != 0);
    fs.Close();
    ftpStream.Close();

}
```

Comment: Make sure you register the DoWork event using '+='.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have access to the FTP server an could check the logs on there?

Comment: @jdweng i just started coding with c# if you can show me how.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel i do not have any error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```